# Opengl texture initialization process

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I have a simple openGL question, currently I'm trying to learn texturing and here is the part I`m confused about it :

```
void initTextures()
{   
   GLuint gTextureSphere;
   int width, height, channels = 1;
    unsigned char* textureMapData = SOIL_load_image("res/texturemap.jpg", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);

    //texture map
    glGenTextures(1,&gTextureSphere);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,gTextureSphere);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureMapData);

    SOIL_free_image_data(textureMapData);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(gProgramSphere, "normalTexture"), 0);
    ////////////////////////

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
}
```

I think the code above reads my image "texturemap.jpg" by `SOIL_load_image` function and store it at `textureMapData` variable. Now, I want to know that, what is the purpose of following 4 lines. I mean, I have already read the data. Am I putting this data into gTextureSphere variable with these following 4 lines ? I guess it is not possible since gTextureSphere is a GLuint type variable. Could anyone explain me ?

Comment: gTextureSphere is the HANDLE to your texture. The four lines in question create a new texture and upload the data from RAM to GPU memory.

Comment: @BDL thanks for reply, what do yo mean by HANDLE? and one more question, after these lines, if I want to access my texture, should I call gTextureSphere variable ?

Comment: Every opengl object is specified via a handle. This is just an integer identifying the object. You access textures using the appropriate OpenGL functions and you should definitly read a introductory tutorial to OpenGL.

Comment: OpenGL is still somewhat based around a "Client/Server" architecture where your program represents the client and you need to "upload the data to the server" in a sense. This often (but not always) entails copying the image data from your programs memory into the GPUs own memory.

Comment: @PeterT: Actually OpenGL's memory model doesn't know what "GPUs" are. Data can be freely swapped between CPU and GPU memory as required. The true reason for OpenGL using an abstract memory model is, that in a modern OS graphics should not be an exclusive resource, hence there's no artificially imposed memory limit. In fact with OpenGL you're mostly limited by the available system memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I want to know that, what is the purpose of following 4 lines.

So far the texture data has only been loaded into the address space of the program. But OpenGL, the renderer API does not "magically" learn about the availability of that data. Let's break it down:

First generate a OpenGL handle we talk to with OpenGL so that it knows what *texture object* we're talking to it about. The generated handle will be stored in the variable `gTextureSphere`.

```
glGenTextures(1,&gTextureSphere);
```

OpenGL has several "plugs", called *texture units* into which texture objects can be "connected to". This tells OpenGL, that the following operations should happen on texture unit 0 (`GL_TEXTURE0`):

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
```

Next make a connection between the just selected texture unit and the texture object we, and OpenGL came into an agreement to call by the value contained in the variable `gTextureSphere`.

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,gTextureSphere);
```

Now that OpenGL knows, that we're talking about texture unit 0 and a certain texture to be plugged into it, we can tell it to do certain things with the texture object. For example copy the image data, read from a file and decoded into some buffer.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureMapData);
```

At this point OpenGL has a texture object with a working copy of the image data; we can now safely free the buffer we used to decode the image file into, since OpenGL has its own copy now.

Comment: wonderful explanation, I'm really appreciate since you did not only downvote but rather give a satisfactory explanation

Comment: @kemalgunes: Actually I even gave you that one upvote. I don't think your question was in anyway bad. (There are no stupid questions, but many questions are ill researched, but your's was completely valid).

Comment: oki doki. By the way I have one more question, As you know we can access cartesian coordinates of a vertex in glsl part with gl_position variable, is there any similar variable which can be used to access u-v coordinates of a single vertex in glsl ?

Comment: when I look at the web, I've found that there is a gl_multiTextCoor but, I dont use multi texturing. Even if I dont use, can I call gl_multiTexCoor[0] to get my u-v coordinates ?

Comment: Actually I\ve already found that there is a gl_TexCoord variable but I could not find the type of it, I guess it does not a vec2 type. (I think that because when I define a vec2 temp variable and do temp=gl_TexCoord;) compiler says that assignment of incompetible types

Comment: @kemalgunes: Actually the `gl_Position` variable is a vertex shader output variable and must be written to with the right value but the user (=programmer) of the OpenGL API. Usually this involves the transformation of some vertex in attribute with some matrix uniforms. In legacy OpenGL (OpenGL-2.x -- and earlier with GLSL extension), i.e. GLSL version <= 120 there used to be predefined built-in variables matching the fixed function pipeline built-in state and render stages. It is not recommendable to use these built-in variables in new programs, since they're removed from core profile OpenGL.

Comment: actually my glsl version is 120, therefore, do you know what is the name of this predefined variable that is used to get u-v coordinates ?

Comment: @kemalgunes: In the vertex shader the input attributes are called `gl_MultiTexCoord[0..8]` corresponding to the texture coordinates for the (at least) 7 available texture units (`GL_TEXTURE0` .. `GL_TEXTURE7`). You pass them to the fragment shader in the predefined `gl_TexCoord[]` varying and use them in the fragment shader accordingly. The reason for having those two distinct variables is, that in the earliest GLSL versions it *was* possible to have just a fragment or a vertex shader.

Comment: @kemalgunes: *However, be advised, that it's not necessary to use those built-in variables.* **In fact it is advisable not to use them at all** but instead to define one's own attributes and varyings. The reason for that is simple: It makes porting shaders and programs to modern OpenGL exponentially easier. Oh, and if you thought you'd get texture coordinates for free... That was never the case, you always have to supply texture coordinates in some way.

Comment: actually I think I've made preprocess required to obtain u-v coordinates in the glsl part but somehow I've failed. I would like to show that part of my code also but character limitation does not allow me, could you please move our conversation into chat ?

Comment: or you can send me an email: mokoko400@gmail.com if you have a couple of minutes

Comment: @kemalgunes: Just put the code in a pastebin or Github Gist, I'll take a look.

Comment: I really appreciate but some part of my code include some privacy so could I just send it via mail to you ?